# Зависимости grpc слетели и не хотят устанавливаться

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, grpc, .net-6

Создал новый проект grpc вчера, все работало нормально. Сегодня запустил этот же проект и он потерял все зависимости grpc которые были(пакет grpc.aspNetCore)
. В связи с рабочей обстановкой, скачивание файлов nuget невозможно, однако удалось скачать все зависимости и перенести файлы пакетов на пк. Вопрос - как установить эти пакеты и настроить зависимости, и почему могли отвалиться зависимости? И почему при попытке установить пакеты через nuget для всех без исключения пакет выдаёт «превышение времени ожидания http...”? Vs2022, .net 6.0

Comment: Все зависимости в .csproj файле.

Comment: Просто создал еще один проект такой же, прикрутил туда пакеты скачанные с сайта nuget и собственно все. В чем была причина сброса пакетов - неизвестно.

Comment: сравните csproj файлы